# LUIS distinguishing between statements and questions

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

Can LUIS reliably differentiate between questions and statements?

We are designing a process flow which will differ depending on whether an utterance contains a question. We can't rely on users using obvious tokens like question marks.

I could train a model with a number of utterances with question type syntax and flag those as Question intent, while those without have a None intent? Seems like this might be a fairly standard requirement and wonder if there's some existing generic solution

Answer (score 0):

LUIS is intended to differentiate between utterances not only based on the question marks. However the tokens that appear iteratively in one intent and not in al others would be used to distinguish the difference based on the learnt models. If you replicate all the questions in one intent in the none intent without the question mark the only identifier that would evolve is the question mark. Which apparently is not what you want. This is also not the function of the none-intent. The question could present itself in multiple forms and what you want is to cover these forms and then add none-question type statements that are not directly related to the none-intent. This would capture tokens that are relevant like "What is", "Where is" "What if" etc... and not just the question mark